# Store a string or numeric value in excel work sheet object properties

Tags: c#, vba, excel

My intention is to store a string/numeric value in work sheet object properties, that should not readable and writable to the user.

I have tried like below, but getting exception.

```
Excel.Worksheet ws = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
ws._CodeName = "abc";
```

Is there any possibility to store custom values in work sheet object

Comment: Exactly what exception are you getting? Have you considered locking & hiding a column in a worksheet : https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1280-excel-protect-hidden-columns.html

Comment: Is there any reason why it needs to be in the sheet?

Comment: @QHarr: For each sheet I need to store Request ID, that would not visible to user

Comment: One more thing I don't want to store in sheet cells, my intention is store value in sheet properties

Comment: The reason i was asking was because you could store it as the sheet codename   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-codename-property-excel

Comment: I have tried to store as codename, but getting error like "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'
"

Comment: There is a `CustomProperties` property of the Worksheet object.  This can be done in VBA; don't know about `c#`  See [Worksheet.CustomProperties Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-customproperties-property-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your code is `c#` you also show a VBA tag, so here is a VBA routine to add a customproperty to a worksheet:

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim sCPName As String
    Dim sCPValue As String
    Dim I As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet1")
    sCPName = "Request ID"
    sCPValue = 12345

With WS.CustomProperties
    For I = 1 To .Count
        If .Item(I).Name = sCPName Then Exit For
    Next I

    If I > .Count Then
        .Add sCPName, sCPValue
    Else
        .Item(I).Value = sCPValue
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ron Rosenfeld

Answer (score 0):

`ws._CodeName` is a ReadOnly property ([MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._worksheet.codename.aspx)). Thus, you can only read it, and not overwrite it.

However, if you want to change the name of a worksheet, this is a possible scenario:

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

class Startup
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook wkbReport = Open(excelApp, @"C:\Testing.xlsx");
        Excel.Worksheet ws = wkbReport.Worksheets[1];
        Console.WriteLine(ws._CodeName);
        ws.Name = "ABC";
        Console.WriteLine("END");
        excelApp.Visible = true;        
    }

    public static Excel.Workbook Open(Excel.Application excelInstance, string fileName, bool readOnly = false, bool editable = true, bool updateLinks = true)
    {
        Excel.Workbook book = excelInstance.Workbooks.Open(
            fileName, updateLinks, readOnly,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, editable, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        return book;
    }
}
```

This is how it would look like:

[image]